How drop unused column with dbms_redefinition in Oracle database?
I don't really understand how to delete columns using the dbms_redefinition utility. All the time there are some strange errors and data overwriting. Disabled foreign keys appear in other tables and are not deleted. Indexes are duplicated... If anyone understands how to use this utility, then please help. I would also like to hear about the pitfalls, if there are any and an explanation of each step
I use the following sequence:

First, I mark the columns in table A as unused (ALTER TABLE A SET UNUSED (...))

Generating DDL to create a new table without unused columns (SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'A') FROM dual) and create table A_temporary

And finally I use dbms_redefinition:
DECLARE
    p_owner    varchar2(30) := 'user';
    orig_table varchar2(30) := 'A';
    int_table  varchar2(30) := 'A_temporary';
BEGIN
    DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE(p_owner, orig_table, int_table, NULL, dbms_redefinition.cons_use_pk);
END;
/

DECLARE
    p_owner    varchar2(30) := 'user';
    orig_table varchar2(30) := 'A';
    int_table  varchar2(30) := 'A_temporary';
    num_errors PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS(p_owner, orig_table, int_table, dbms_redefinition.cons_orig_params, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, num_errors);
END;
/

SELECT OBJECT_NAME, BASE_TABLE_NAME, DDL_TXT
FROM DBA_REDEFINITION_ERRORS;

DECLARE
    p_owner    varchar2(30) := 'user';
    orig_table varchar2(30) := 'A';
    int_table  varchar2(30) := 'A_temporary';
BEGIN
    DBMS_REDEFINITION.SYNC_INTERIM_TABLE(p_owner, orig_table, int_table);
END;
/

DECLARE
    p_owner    varchar2(30) := 'user';
    orig_table varchar2(30) := 'A';
    int_table  varchar2(30) := 'A_temporary';
BEGIN
    DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE(p_owner, orig_table, int_table);
END;
/

DROP TABLE A_temporary CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE
/



I took this instruction from here. Is everything okay in it in the three steps that I take and I shouldn't have any problems, or am I using it incorrectly and you have any comments?
The purpose of the idea is to achieve fast physical deletion of columns
P.S. The table I'm doing this for has a lot of relationships with other tables and takes up a lot of disk space (about 200 GB)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78332874/how-do-i-delete-a-columns-from-a-large-oracle-database/78334516#78334516

Um, there is indeed a mention that you can use dbms_redefinition, but not a word about how to use it. What is this link for?

To explain how you don't need to do this at all. There's really no pressing benefit to getting the column out completely. Just reorg the table with alter table move to remove an unused col from the data blocks and free up the space. It's then gone both logically and physically.

Wouldn't that lock the table?

you can do an online table move alter table .. move parallel (degree 16) update indexes online that does not block DMLs, except that it requires a brief exclusive lock at the very end to swap the segments.

@PaulW Is this command capable of loading 100% of the entire CPU? It is quite a computational operation, and if this happens, then the database will be blocked for the duration of the rebuild due to the high load on the CPU. Or shouldn't that be the case? I mean alter table .. move parallel (degree 16) update indexes online command

Unless Oracle decides to queue CPU no process should be blocked (as far as Oracle is concerned) by another sitting on CPU, though if there is a CPU shortage at the OS level it certainly will degrade performance across the board. Whether parallel(degree 16) is too much depends on your SMP architecture. If you have 16 cores or more and the system isn't already heavily loaded, a DOP of 16 should be fine, especially since it'll spend a significant portion of its time on I/O, not just CPU. Adjust the DOP to your architecture.

According to the tech note https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=534544425586275&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=HOWTO&id=1120704.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=13cxb22k6m_4
you are doing almost the same thing, but some differences:
they don't play with the UNUSED column, so once you have your new interim table, I would re-enable the column before the start_redef_table, in case it has some unexpected side effects,
they always do a DBMS_REDEFINITION.CAN_REDEF_TABLE to be sure
they use explicit column mapping (col_mapping argument) when calling DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE
and
DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS is the latest thing they do before dbms_redefinition.finish_redef_table and thus AFTER START_REDEF_TABLE.
